# Cannot get Colorbox trigger to Display image as a link and link to Body of node

Tags: views, javascript

I am using Colorbox and Colorbox Node modules in combination with Views.

I would like to link images (displayed in a view) to the respective body fields of the nodes.

In my view, I am trying to use a Colorbox trigger field. I would like it to display an image and link it to the Body. However, the image seems to be opeing up a new page and displaying the same image... How do I get it to display the body of the nodes instead?

I've got the trigger field set to Image
Popup is set to

I've ticked Rewrite the output of this field, and set the text to

I've also ticked the Output this field as a link option, and set the Link path to:
http://mysiteurl[path] 
I've also set the Link class to colorbox-node

What am I missing in order to get the Image to link to the Body of the node, and display it in a pop up, not a full new page?

Answer (score 1):

The order of the fields are important when you're using 'Rewrite the output as field' option.

In my views, I took the following fields

1. Path - (Exclude from display)
2. Image
3. Title

In the rewrite the output as field option, I did the following thing with the help of tokens from Replacement Patterns.

`<a href="[path]" class="colorbox-node" data-inner-width="600" data-inner-height="600">[field_profile_image]</a>`

And yes, this did work.

I'm able to get my page's body in popup when ever I click on an image.